# How to disable WPF animation

Tags: c#, wpf

I have this code and cannot figure out how to disable the animation.

Any clue? Thank you!

```
      #region Blinking Animation
            Storyboard sb = new Storyboard();
            if (IsImageBlinking)
            {
                DoubleAnimation da = new DoubleAnimation();

                da.From = 1.0;
                da.To = 0.0;
                da.RepeatBehavior = RepeatBehavior.Forever;
                da.AutoReverse = true;


                sb.Children.Add(da);
                Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(da, new PropertyPath("(Image.Opacity)"));
                Storyboard.SetTarget(da, image1);
                sb.Begin();
            }
            else // This code doesn't disable the animation :(
            {
//!!!! Here I need to disable the animation.  
                sb.Stop();
                sb.Children.Clear();
            }

            #endregion
```

Comment: when do you want to disable the animation?

Comment: Are you aware of the fact that you create a *new* Storyboard each time you call this code?

Comment: @Clemens is correct. Try declaring the sb as member variable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It works if you use the *same* Storyboard instance for `Begin` and `Stop`. Declare `sb` as a member of your class:

```
public class MainWindow
{
    private Storyboard sb = new Storyboard();

    ...
}
```

Comment: Once you have the storyboard field you can call methods `Begin()` and `Stop()` to begin/stop the animation.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using `sb.BeginAnimation(Image.OpacityProperty, null);` instead of `sb.stop()`?